# Javascript won't split using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, split, regex-lookarounds

Since I started writing this question, I think I figured out the answers to every question I had, but I thought I'd post anyway, as it might be useful to others and more clarification might be helpful.

I was trying to use a regular expression with lookahead with the javascript function split.  For some reason it was not splitting the string even though it finds a match when I call match.  I originally thought the problem was from using lookahead in my regular expression. Here is a simplified example:

Doesn't work:

```
"aaaaBaaaa".split("(?=B).");
```

Works:

```
"aaaaBaaaa".match("(?=B).");
```

It appears the problem was that in the split example, the passed string wasn't being interpreted as a regular expression.  Using forward slashes instead of quotes seems to fix the problem.

```
"aaaaBaaaa".split(/(?=B)./);
```

I confirmed my theory with the following silly looking example:

```
"aaaaaaaa(?=B).aaaaaaa".split("(?=B).");
```

Does anyone else think it's strange that the match function assumes you have a regular expression while the split function does not?

Comment: I've always used the /regex/ (no quotes) syntax for everything:  match, split, replace.  I didn't realize you didn't have to in some cases.

Comment: Actually it makes sense to let match() assume a regex (what *else* would there be that you can match against?) and split() assume a string, since splitting on a string is probably faster than splitting on a regex. Only if you pass an actual regex to split(), it will do the slower regex splitting.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**`String.split`** accepts either a string or regular expression as its first parameter. The **`String.match`** method only accepts a regular expression.

I'd imagine that **`String.match`** will try and work with whatever is passed; so if you pass a string it will interpret it as a regular expression. The **`String.split`** method doesn't have the luxury of doing this because it can accept regular expressions AND strings; in this case it would be foolish to second-guess.

---

**Edit**: (From: "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide")

**`String.match`** requires a regular expression to work with. The passed argument needs to be a **`RegExp`** object that specifies the pattern to be matched. If this argument is not a **`RegExp`**, it is first converted to one by passing it to the **`RegExp()`** constructor.

Answer (score 3):

If I recall correctly (and I could be very wrong here), the split method was implemented in javascript before the regex engine was in wide use, so it's presumably for backward compatibility.

Comment: I think this holds; String.split was introduced in 1.1 and Regular Expressions in 1.2. Reading the docs about `split()` (here: http://wp.netscape.com/eng/mozilla/3.0/handbook/javascript/newfunc.htm), and the regex enhancements to `split()` here: http://web.archive.org/web/20010408055419/developer.netscape.com/docs/manuals/communicator/jsguide/js1_2.htm (no direct link, look under 'Regular Expressions'->'String methods'