# Regex needed to split a string by "."

Tags: javascript, regex

I am in need for a regex in Javascript. I have a string:

```
'*window.some1.some\.2.(a.b + ")" ? cc\.c : d.n [a.b, cc\.c]).some\.3.(this.o.p ? ".mike." [ff\.]).some5'
```

I want to split this string by periods such that I get an array:

```
[
    '*window',
    'some1',
    'some\.2',   //ignore the . because it's escaped
    '(a.b ? cc\.c : d.n [a.b, cc\.c])',  //ignore everything inside ()
    'some\.3',
    '(this.o.p ? ".mike." [ff\.])',
    'some5'
]
```

What regex will do this?

Comment: What about `{foo.bar}`, etc...

Comment: What are you trying to do with this. It sounds like you want something more powerful then a regex...

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812144/javascript-wont-split-using-regex/812236#812236?

Comment: A split will always return a simple string or something in parenthesis. So I will never end up with {foo.bar}

Comment: Friend, you are in need of a full-fledged parser...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var string = '*window.some1.some\\.2.(a.b + ")" ? cc\\.c : d.n [a.b, cc\\.c]).some\\.3.(this.o.p ? ".mike." [ff\\.]).some5';
var pattern = /(?:\((?:(['"])\)\1|[^)]+?)+\)+|\\\.|[^.]+?)+/g;
var result = string.match(pattern);
result = Array.apply(null, result); //Convert RegExp match to an Array
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/66Zfh/3/**
Explanation of the RegExp. Match a consecutive set of characters, satisfying:

```
/             Start of RegExp literal
(?:            Create a group without reference (example: say, group A)
   \(          `(` character
   (?:         Create a group without reference (example: say, group B)
      (['"])     ONE `'` OR `"`, group 1, referable through `\1` (inside RE)
      \)         `)` character
      \1         The character as matched at group 1, either `'` or `"`
     |          OR
      [^)]+?     Any non-`)` character, at least once (see below)
   )+          End of group (B). Let this group occur at least once
  |           OR
   \\\.        `\.` (escaped backslash and dot, because they're special chars)
  |           OR
   [^.]+?      Any non-`.` character, at least once (see below)
)+            End of group (A). Let this group occur at least once
/g           "End of RegExp, global flag"
        /*Summary: Match everything which is not satisfying the split-by-dot
                 condition as specified by the OP*/
```

There's a difference between `+` and `+?`. A single plus attempts to match as much characters as possible, while a `+?` matches only these characters which are necessary to get the RegExp match. *Example: `123 using \d+? > 1 and \d+ > 123`*.

The `String.match` method performs a global match, because of the `/g`, global flag. The `match` function with the `g` flag returns an array consisting of all matches subsequences.

When the `g` flag is omitted, only the first match will be selected. The array will then consist of the following elements:

```
Index 0: <Whole match>
Index 1: <Group 1>
```

Comment: I am developing a Javascript binding framework. The splitted values are property chains. The above example is something I quickly made up. The above example really means ...

Comment: *window (javascript window object)
has a property called "some1" has a property called 
some\.2 
evaluate the expression a.b ? cc\.c : d.n whenever a.b OR cc\.c changes 
and so on and so forth.

Hope this answers the question and sorry about the multiple posts. Hitting the enter button does a post instead of a new line.

Comment: This is not correct. (a.b ? cc\.c : d.n [a.b, cc\.c]) you split this result, while you shouldn't.

Comment: @FailedDev Updated, it now correctly deals with quoted parentheses.

Comment: Rob W, <BR>
Seems like this might be the solution.<BR>

Slight change to the string, adding ')'<BR>
*window.some1.some\.2.(a.b + ")" + ')' ? cc\.c : d.n [a.b, cc\.c]).some\.3.(this.o.p ? ".mike." [ff\.]).some5

Comment: @user1031396 HTML doesn't work in comments. Only very basic mark-down (links and code using a backtick) are enabled.

Comment: @RobW Thks. Rewriting the above comment.  Slight change to the string, adding ')' in the string to be splitted. *window.some1.some\.2.(a.b + ")" + ')' ? cc\.c : d.n [a.b, cc\.c]).some\.3.(this.o.p ? ".mike." [ff\.]).some5

Comment: What do you mean? The current expression returns the results as requested in the question. If you want additional features, create a new question, linking to this one, because the current answers are aimed at your current question.

Comment: @Rob W, can you please post an explanation of your regex. It will help me maintain it in the future.

Comment: @Rob W, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The regex below :

```
result = subject.match(/(?:(\(.*?[^'"]\)|.*?[^\\])(?:\.|$))/g);
```

Can be used to acquire the desired results. Group 1 has the results since you want to omit the `.`

Use this :

```
var myregexp = /(?:(\(.*?[^'"]\)|.*?[^\\])(?:\.|$))/g;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
while (match != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
        // matched text: match[i]
    }
    match = myregexp.exec(subject);
}
```

**Explanation :**

```
// (?:(\(.*?[^'"]\)|.*?[^\\])(?:\.|$))
// 
// Match the regular expression below «(?:(\(.*?[^'"]\)|.*?[^\\])(?:\.|$))»
//    Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\(.*?[^'"]\)|.*?[^\\])»
//       Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «\(.*?[^'"]\)»
//          Match the character “(” literally «\(»
//          Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
//             Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
//          Match a single character NOT present in the list “'"” «[^'"]»
//          Match the character “)” literally «\)»
//       Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «.*?[^\\]»
//          Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
//             Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
//          Match any character that is NOT a “A \ character” «[^\\]»
//    Match the regular expression below «(?:\.|$)»
//       Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «\.»
//          Match the character “.” literally «\.»
//       Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «$»
//          Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any) «$»
```

Comment: your solution works too but leaves a period in the end. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is notoriously difficult to use a Regex to do balanced parenthesis matching, especially in Javascript.

You would be way better off creating your own parser. Here's a clever way to do this that will utilize the strength of Regex's:

- Create a Regex that matches and captures any "pattern of interest" - `/(?:(\\.)|([\(\[\{])|([\)\]\}])|(\.))/g`
- Use `string.replace(pattern, function (...))`, and in the function, keep a count of opening braces and closing braces.
- Add the matching text to a buffer.
- If the split character is found and the opening and closing braces are balanced, add the buffer to your results array.

This solution will take a bit of work, and requires knowledge of closures, and you should probably see the documentation of `string.replace`, but I think it is a great way to solve your problem!

**Update**:
After noticing the number of questions related to this one, I decided to take on the above challenge.
[Here is the live code to use a Regex to split a string](http://jsfiddle.net/ScottRippey/ZQLBX/21/).
This code has the following features:

- Uses a Regex pattern to find the splits
- Only splits if there are **balanced parenthesis**
- Only splits if there are **balanced quotes**
- Allows escaping of parenthesis, quotes, and splits using `\`

This code will work perfectly for your example.

Answer (score 0):

not need regex for this work.

```
var s = '*window.some1.some\.2.(a.b + ")" ? cc\.c : d.n [a.b, cc\.c]).some\.3.(this.o.p ? ".mike." [ff\.]).some5';

console.log(s.match(/(?:\([^\)]+\)|.*?\.)/g));
```

output:

```
  ["*window.", "some1.", "some.", "2.", "(a.b + ")", "" ? cc.", "c : d.", "n [a.", "b, cc.", "c]).", "some.", "3.", "(this.o.p ? ".mike." [ff.])", "."]
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to meet the requirements of the question (ignoring `\.`, and ignoring `.` inside parentheses...)

Comment: Yet this isn't what the OP wanted. The OP wanted that text inside of the `()` will remain as one unit (even though there are dots inside of it), and an escaped dot (`/.`) should be ignored as well.

Comment: This is the first time I have posted a question on stackflow and am amazed at the quick responses. Thanks stacksflow and thanks to all who responded.

Answer (score 0):

So, was working with this, and now I see that @FailedDev is rather not a failure, since that was pretty nice. :)

Anyhow, here's my solution. I'll just post the regex only.

```
((\(.*?((?<!")\)(?!")))|((\\\.)|([^.]))+)
```

Sadly this won't work in your case however, since I'm using negative lookbehind, which I don't think is supported by javascript regex engine. It should work as intended in other engines however, as can be confirmed here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/. Replace with $1\n.

Comment: As you have mentioned, you're using a look-behind, which are not supported in JavaScript. Even if look-behinds were supported, `?!` has to be `?=` (look-ahead).

Comment: No, I wanted negative lookbehind, not lookahead. I wanted to match the ) character that's not preceded by a " character => Negative lookbehind.

Comment: I am referring to the `?!` (at `\)(?!`). You want to match a parenthesis which is preceded and postfixed by a double-quote character.

Comment: In that case, no I want to end my match at the first ) which is not enclosed in double quotes. So I want to match a parenthesis which is not preceded nor postfixed by double-quote characters. So my reasoning was sound. I do see a bug in it however, but I'm not going to point it out for you since you're poking at me. :)