# Not sure why my regex is grabbing a few blank items

Tags: regex

I've got this regex:
`([a-z]+)(?:\.)`.

Using it in Javascript like this:
`"test.thing.other".split(/([a-z]+)(?:\.)/);` ends up giving me an array like this:
`["", "test", "", "thing", "other"]`.
I have no idea why the first and third elements are being put into that array.  Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: why don't you just split on the period? .. without the regex? http://stackoverflow.com/a/96452/195488

Comment: @0A0D : Because this is only the beginning of a complex Regex test.  I'm just at step one so far.

Comment: So what about this? /[\s.]+/

Comment: That works perfectly against "split".  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your question and comment **"Capture a-z until a period"** I believe you should be rather using String.match like this:

```
arr = "test.thing.other".match(/[a-z]+(?=\.)/g);
```

gives:

```
["test", "thing"]
```

Comment: You are correct.  When "split" starting giving me results closer to what I wanted I started using that.  I now see that I shouldn't.

Comment: Good answer – but an explanation would be nice, in particular since your expression is using zero-width lookahead assertions which aren’t widely known.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Thanks for the nice words. My answer was based on my understanding of OP's question and comments. OP mentioned that he wants to `Capture a-z until a period"` which in other words means he wants to capture `[a-z]+` if it is followed by a period. That requirements is easily met by using a positive lookahead `(?=\.)` as I used in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The parentheses are the reason. Here’s what [MDN says on `string.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) says:

> If `separator` is a regular expression that contains capturing parentheses, then each time separator is matched the results (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output array.

They also caution:

> However, not all browsers support this capability.

So this result may be inconsistent. If you just want to split by the content of the expression, remove the parentheses:

```
>> 'test.thing.other'.split(/[a-z]+\./)
["", "", "other"]
```

Which may also not be what you want, but is the intuitively expected result given your expression.

If you want to split by dot then you need to provide exactly that in the regular expression: a dot.

```
>> 'test.thing.other'.split(/\./)
["test", "thing", "other"]
```

Comment: @0A0D you are testing the *matcher*, not the output of `split`. These methods behave very differently but if you check the “global” option on your test page you’ll nevertheless get a consistent result.

Comment: Hmm, its an odd syntax nonetheless. I wonder if this applies: http://stackoverflow.com/a/812179/195488

Comment: @KonradRudolph : That ends up nowhere near capturing what I want.  My expression says: "Capture a-z until a period", which is exactly what I want.  I still don't see how that ends up returning two blank instances based on the given string.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Yes, global gets you two matches. You would think that it would return the matches.. what else is it splitting really. Its an odd way to do a split.

Comment: I think I see the mistake... you have to match on the period. Split does return the matches, in a sense.

Comment: @0A0D Only if you use capturing groups in the expression, otherwise `split` does exactly what you’d normally expect from a splitting function, i.e. it uses the expression as the separator.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I see, its still weird. Use `match` instead.

Comment: @James Well your question said “I have no idea why the first and third elements are being put into that array” which implies that your expected result was equal to my last example.

Comment: @KonradRudolph : Check my result again.  The first and third items are blank strings.  :P

Comment: @James Exactly: and if you take those out (because they were unexpected) you get, as the remainder, `["test", "string", "other"]` which is the result from my expression.